# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll Can anyone help me with this error?

Tags: c#

```
//Skier ID
private void frmNewSkier_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    readFromTextFile();

    int lastSkierID = Convert.ToInt32(previousSkiers[previousSkiers.GetLength(0) - 1, 0]);

    int nextSkierID = lastSkierID + 1;

    txtSkierID.Text = nextSkierID.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can handle exception:

```
try
{
 readFromTextFile();

int lastSkierID = Convert.ToInt32(previousSkiers[previousSkiers.GetLength(0) - 1, 0]);

int nextSkierID = lastSkierID + 1;

txtSkierID.Text = nextSkierID.ToString();
}
catch (FormatException e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} FormatException Message", e.Message);
    // Return? Loop round? Whatever.
}
```